# How can I design above product card in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I code the below product card in flutter and make it responsive for all devices?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Column` to align the image, discount, and price vertically. You can use the image as the `DecorationImage` of the first `Container`. For the discount, you can use a `FractionalTranslation` with a y-axis offset of `-0.5` to position it half its size upper. You can do the same to position the price upper.

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://cf.shopee.ph/file/6907c52b5698df501bf2fd83e803d6d2')))),
          FractionalTranslation(
            translation: Offset(0, -0.5),
            child: Container(
              width: 160,
              height: 70,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                '-99%',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),
          FractionalTranslation(
            translation: Offset(0, -1),
            child: Text(
              'US \$0.01',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 28),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: Hi @Mobina, is it the best practice to use the `FractionalTranslation`? Why don't we use `Stack`?

Comment: `FractionalTranslation` is much easier to work with. If you use `Stack`, you need to set all the positions according to the sizes of the widgets (in this example, you would need to set the first container's `top` to half the height of the discount and the discount's `top` to the container's height and so on). Also, if you would change a widget's size, you would need to change all the positions accordingly. @hisam

Comment: Ah, I see. So that's your reason to use the `FractionalTranslation` widget. Thanks for replying @Mobina

Answer (score 0):

- Make the background image container and the discount percentage
  container children of stack.
- Add BoxDecoration to background image container with borderRadius
  property.
- Make the width of the background image container equal to the width
  of the device obtained from MediaQuery.
- Use Positioned widget for the discount percentage indicator to push
  it to the bottom center.

This ensures the unit remains responsive on any device size